# Testing a job in Dashing

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, jobs, dashing

I am building an application with Dashing/Smashing right now, and I am using rspec to test my code. However, I cannot figure out how to check that `send_event` is called. I have tried

`expect(Sinatra::Application).to receive(:send_event).twice`

and

`expect(Dashing).to receive(:send_event).twice`,

but neither have worked. I am not sure what object is supposed to receive the call to `send_event` since it lies inside Dashing in `app.rb`. There is also [this issue](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/615), talking about the same thing, unanswered on the Dashing GitHub.

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**Update:**

I still have not figured out how to do this, but I have discovered that this works:

```
let(:dummy_class) { Class.new { include Dashing } }

context 'something' do
    it 'does something' do
        expect(dummy_class).to receive(:send_event).once
        dummy_class.send('send_event', 'test', current: 'test')
    end
end
```

However, if I use the method I want to call that contains `send_event` as opposed to doing `dummy_class.send(...)`, then it does not recognize that the method was called. It must have to do with my test not using the dummy class. I don't know if there is any way to get around this and make it use the dummy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Do not call `send_event` directly within the job. Call it within some other class, perhaps called `EventSender`. Then, to test that `send_event` is called, treat it as though it is an instance method of that class instead of a method of a module. Your code might look like this, for example:

```
describe 'something' do
    context 'something' do
        it 'does something' do
            happy_es = EventSender.new(...)
            expect(happy_es).to receive(:send_event).with(...)
            happy_es.method_that_calls_sendevent
        end
    end
end
```

Hope this helps someone who is struggling with the same thing. :)